# Keep an images link clickable on hover

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So my img is clickable but since I have added some caption hover effects, it does not allow me to click the image/caption. What I'd like is for the img to remain clickable even when the caption is shown on top i.e. set the whole caption to be clickable. Each way I have tried to anchor the img or caption, I still can't click it.

HTML:

```
<div class = "post-thumb">
    <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
    <div class = "caption">
        <h4><a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
        <p><?php $content = get_the_content('Read more');
            print $content;?>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.singlecolumnpost .post {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 5px;
}

.twocolumnpost .post {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0px 0px;
}

.singlecolumnpost img, .singlecolumnpost iframe {
    display: block;
    max-width: 940px;
    max-height: 529px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

.twocolumnpost img, .twocolumnpost iframe {
    max-width: 460px;
    max-height: 259px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

/* caption effects */

.caption {
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.caption h4, .caption p {
    padding: 20px 10px;
}

.post-thumb:hover .caption {
    opacity: 0.75;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 75);
    transition: opacity 0.25s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s;
}

/* end caption effects */
```

So what's the correct way, and a way that works, to keep the image clickable?

Comment: Place your anchor tag `<a>` *outside* of the `<div class="caption">`. And of course, close it properly (after the `</div>`).

Comment: Paste rendered HTML and your JS coce as well.

Comment: ^ and the relevant CSS!

Comment: Placing the anchor outside of caption has no effect. Added CSS.